# When can I remove "yet" from a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning, ellipsis

When can I remove "yet" from a sentence?

I can say for example:

> "Has the teacher arrived yet?"

OR

> "Has the teacher arrived?"

is there any difference in meaning between these sentences?

And when can I remove it from a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence with "yet" suggests some impatience. You would use it if you wondered whether the teacher was in the building shortly before the class was to start.

Without "yet" you just want to know whether the teacher has arrived, with no particular need for them to be there right now.

Note: I am not addressing the grammar here, just what the sentences say/suggest.

Answer (score -4):

Your question looks like you want to know more about the word "yet"

"yet" is an adverb and also can be used as an conjunction.

"yet" is used  in situations like below.

A is doing now homework and hasn't finished it. Then A can say "I have not finished homework **yet**"

A's mom can ask "Have you finished homework yet?" and you say "No, not yet"

"yet" is also used as a conjunction meaning "nevertheless" as below.

> It’s a small car, yet it’s surprisingly spacious.(conjunction)

You can use both "Has the teacher arrived yet?" OR "Has the teacher arrived?" to ask a question. The only difference is just an adjunct of "yet".

"yet" is the opposite of "already": they imply "already is positive" and "yet is negative",

for example, it's used like this - already arrived? or arrived?, arrived yet? or arrived?